# Correct sentence construction using before

Tags: sentence-construction

Can we use past participls after before?

He finished his work before his boss arrived.

Or

He finished his work before his boss arrives.

Comment: I don't understand the reference to "past participle"; there are no past participles in either sentence. All verbs except the last one, _arrives_, are past tense. _Arrives_ is present tense, and it's incorrect in this context. The first sentence, with all past tense verbs, is correct.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't use a past participle there.

*Before* is followed by either a noun phrase (eg "before lunch"; "before his arrival") or a finite clause (a clause with a finite verb - eg "before I arrive"; "before they eat").

The clause following *before* in both your examples is fine: "before his boss arrives" (so-called "present tense") and "before his boss arrived" (past tense - not past participle).

However, the second sentence doesn't make sense, because "he finished" is past, and "before his boss arrives" is future.* The first sentence is fine, and almost certainly what you wanted to say.

*You may be surprised that I say this is future. I guess most people will say it is present, because it contains the so-called present tense. I say that it is either timeless-habitual ("Every day he finishes his work before his boss arrives") or future ( "He'll finish his work before his boss arrives"). It's hard to come up with a context in which it can have present meaning.

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence

> He finished his work before his boss arrived.

is good. The second sentence would be better as

> He finishes his work before his boss arrives.

being a [present tense narrative](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PresentTenseNarrative).

Both sentences now use the same tense in each part.